# Implement an Encoder and Decoder architecture with attention mechanism

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model, encoder-decoder

I want to implement Encoder-Decoder with attention mechanism from scratch. Can anyone please help me with the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62173658/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good place to start [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)